# Color Formatting depending on it's value in html

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Please update:</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#bfff00">ID</th>
    <th bgcolor="#bfff00">S</th>
    <th bgcolor="#bfff00">R</th>
    <th bgcolor="#bfff00">D</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>{hyper}</td>'
    <td>{r}</td>
    <td>{c[:-8]}</td>
    <td>{diff1}</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
t = (i["f"]["c"])
    dt = int(t[8:10])
    m = int(t[5:7])
    yr = int(t[0:4])
    Date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    # print(Date)
    today = datetime.date.today()
    someday = datetime.date(yr, m, dt)
    diff = today - someday
    diff = str(diff.days)
    diff1=int(diff)
```

I am actually reading from the json file the current date and diff1 will be the difference of today's date and the json file dates present.So,I need to highlight the diff when it is greater than 4.
I want to print diff1 in red if it's value is greater than 4,How do i do it?Please help.I want to know how to do conditional formatting in html

Comment: what kind of templating engine/language are you using?

Comment: I am using python and incorporating the data in html table format

Comment: it's unclear from your HTML code how you replace the variables (such as `diff1`) to the actual values, please expand your code a bit, because the solution will likely depend on it

Comment: Well, you must already have a mechanism which reads the HTML template and replaces fields such as `{diff1}` with values. Have this mechanism replace `{diff1}` with `<span style="color: red" >` *value* `</span>` if the *value* is greater than 4.

Comment: yes i have diff1 value and i am just formatting here in html tag using f tag in python,I just want here as whenever diff1 value is greater than 4 the value appears in color red

Comment: @AlexP how to add condition <span style="color: red" > value </span> in diff1

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are doing. The code which you have shown in the question *does not include any kind of numbers*, less than 4, equal to 4, or greater than 4. It includes *fields* such  as `{hyper}` or `{diff1}`. Somehow these fields get populated with numbers. You don't say what this "somehow" is. HTML itself won't do conditional formatting for you. You must do it in the mysterious "somehow" mechanism which replaces the fields with actual numbers.

Comment: I am actually reading from the json file the current date and diff1 will be the difference of today's date and the json file dates present.So,I need to highlight the diff when it is greater than 4.Updated the code,Please have a look.Thanks for your support